# ARM Thumb2 register usage

Tags: disassembly, assembly, arm, thumb2

I am reversing ARM Thumb2 code.

I am looking for a table that shows which registers are used to pass arguments to functions, and which registers must be saved after the function ends.

By the way, if I see `push r5-r9` at the beginning of the function and `pop r5-r9` at the end of function,  are those registers saved?

Answer (score 4):

This is all documented in the ARM Architecture Procedure Call Standard (AAPCS) [ARM IHI0042](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/index.html).  There may be more recent versions.  The short version: R0-R3 are for passing arguments, R12 is a scratch register for procedure calls (linker things, etc) and everything else must be preserved by functions that use it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the Arm Procedure Call Standard (AAPCS) Arm IHI 0042F doc? I would like to take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the `push r5-r9` instruction is a way to save the content of these registers (ie `r5`, `r6`, `r7`, `r8`, `r9`) on the stack, then the `pop r5-r9` is restoring the saved values before leaving the function stack-frame.

This is quite common behavior when you want to manipulate non-volatile registers within your stack-frame and be compliant to the ABI. It is extremely frequent to see these way of doing in compiler generated assembly code.

Comment: So are these typically the registers used to pass arguments to a function (first part of the question!)?

Comment: It depends of the ABI, the question is not precise enough to answer properly. We need to know the OS used (and thus the ABI used).

Comment: @perror, I talking about embbeded without os